# Why can you not move on the last level on Dig Dug?

Tags: software, arcade

The objective of Dig Dug is to eliminate underground monsters by inflating them until they pop, or by squashing them with large rocks. Once all of the monsters have escaped or been defeated, the level progresses.

Once the level number reaches 256, however, a monster appears precisely on Dig Dug's spawn point, no tunnels appear, the rocks are arranged strangely and the player loses all of the remaining lives almost instantly.

Why did the developers program an impossible level into the game?

Comment: Perhaps someone can chime in with a more specific answer, but the general reason is that the programmer never expected anyone to get that far, and contains a machine-language loop equivalent to something like `unsigned char i=level; if (i > 100) i=100; do {...} while(--i);` and didn't expect that the loop would ever run more than 100 times, even though it runs 256 times if `level` is zero.  That's what caused the Pac-Man kill-screen, and something similar could be at play here.

Comment: @supercat This glitch is caused by something different; I'll see if I can get an answer posted today.

Comment: The principle seems to be the same, but without the loop: code checks if a values is greater than X, clips it if so, and then decrements it regardless.  For Pac-Man, the decrement feeds a loop which runs N more times, but the key point is pegging a value before a decrement.

Comment: As for why programmers didn't do anything about that bug, I'd say that as far as the customers are concerned the real bug isn't that the game kills the player on level 256, but rather that it doesn't kill the player off sooner.

Answer (score 29):

Dig Dug stores the positions of objects in tables in memory. There are two tables for this: an enemy table containing the positions of up to four Pookas and four Fygars, and a rock table containing the positions of up to six rocks. There is also a table containing tunnel data, but this is stored in a different way.

The game divides the playable area into this grid:

[image: Dig Dug Memory Grid]
<sup>Image sourced from [DonHodges.com](//donhodges.com/How_Deep_Can_You_Dig_Dug.htm)</sup>

This image shows the mapping between on-screen positions and internal representations. These "position numbers" are stored in the enemy and rock tables to show where to place the enemies and rocks. For example, the enemy table for level 1 might look like this:

```
32 3C DA 00    00 B4 00 00
```

and the rock table might look like this:

```
00 45 AB C4 00 00
```

The enemy table is eight bytes long, but is divided into two sections of four bytes each, for the Pookas and Fygars respectively. The byte value `00` is used for enemies that should not be placed.

There are fifteen different levels in Dig Dug. These are stored in sequential tables, like a C array. There is a piece of code designed to limit the level value to between `00` and `0e`, which is as follows:

1. `LD A,($8627)`: Load the round number into `A`.
2. `CP 16`: Is `A < 16`?
3. `JR C,$1BE9`: If yes, go to instruction 6.
4. `AND #00000011`: Mask `A` with `00000011`, performing modulo 4.
5. `ADD A,12`: Add `12` to `A`, bringing it to between `12` and `15` (inclusive).
6. `DEC A`: Subtract `1` from `A`.
7. `RET`: Return.

This value is then used to calculate the offset of the current level's data. But what happens if we put `0` into it?

1. `LD A,($8627)`: Load `0` into `A`.
2. `CP 16`: Is `A < 16`?
3. `JR C,$1BE9`: Yes, so go to instruction 6.
4. *(skipped because of jump)*
5. *(skipped because of jump)*
6. `DEC A`: Subtract `1` from `A`, underflowing to `255`.
7. `RET`: Return.

With an offset of `255` the game vastly overshoots the tables, setting and using what is known as a "garbage pointer". The game then interprets code and other memory values as a layout, which coincidently results in two enemies being placed on Dig Dug's starting position, rendering the level impossible.

Comment: Hey wizzwizz4, I approved Cactus' suggested edit to your answer because I believe it makes the assembly clearer.  I know I just brought up a question about suggested edits on meta, but I don't feel like this puts words in your mouth.  If you have any questions or feel as if my approval was wrong, feel free to ping me.  Thanks.

Comment: I think your approval was correct; this edit makes the answer much clearer. (Thanks also to @Cactus for suggesting it in the first place!)

Comment: This was an absolutely excellent answer.  Well done!

Comment: and this is the same style of bug that Pac-Man has.

Comment: @peterferrie It's not quite as dramatic, but yes it is.

Comment: Why do you say this code designed to limit the level value within `00` and `0e`? For example, if you give it a value like `1e`, it's greater than 15 so it'll just jump to instruction 6, decrement it and return it.

Comment: @Wilson If it's greater than `0f`, then it _won't_ jump. You're forgetting the `AND`. `1e` would be masked to `02` which would be incremented by `0c` to make `0e`.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Oh yeah, I understand now.